How to prove the sinusoidal response to \$\sin\omega t\$ is the imaginary part of the response to \$e^{j \omega t}\$?
In solving the sinusoidal response of a system to a sine input \$x(t)=\sin\omega t\$ or cosine input \$x(t)=\cos\omega t\$, it is more convenient to compute with Euler's formula \$x(t)=e^{j\omega t}=\cos \omega t + j\sin \omega t\$.  Here, I'm trying to see how a typical transfer function \$H(s)\$ for a RLC voltage divider or a mass-spring-damper system would respond to it.
$$
H(s) =\frac {Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac {1}{s^2+2s+5}=\frac{a_1}{s-p_1}+\frac{a_2}{s-p_2}=\mathcal{L}\{\frac{e^{-t}}{2} sin 2t\} \tag{1}
$$
where \$p_{1,2} = -1 \pm j2\$ are the two complex conjugate poles and \$a_{1,2} =\mp\frac{j}{4}\$ are complex conjugate numbers. If \$X(s) =\mathcal{L}\{e^{j\omega t}\}=\frac{1}{s-j\omega}\$, then
$$
Y(s) =H(s)X(s)=\frac{H(s)}{s-j\omega}=\frac{A_0}{s-p_0}+\frac{A_1}{s-p_1}+\frac{A_2}{s-p_2} \tag{2}
$$
where \$p_0 = j\omega\$, \$A_0=H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{(5-\omega^2)+2j\omega},A_1=\frac{-1}{4(2-\omega+j)},  A_2=\frac{-1}{4(2+\omega-j)}\$.
\begin{align}
Y(t)=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{Y(s)\}&=H(j\omega)e^{j\omega t}-\frac{e^{-t}}{4}(\frac{e^{2jt}}{(2-\omega)+j}+\frac{e^{-2jt}}{(2+\omega)-j})\\\\
&=\frac{\cos\omega t + j \sin\omega t -\frac{e^{-t}}{4}(4 \cos 2 t + 2 \sin 2t +2j\omega \sin 2t)}{(5-\omega^2) + 2 j \omega} \tag{3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
Re\{Y(t)\}&=\frac{(5-\omega ^2) \cos\omega t + 2\omega(\sin \omega t) - e^{-t}\{(5-\omega^2)(\cos 2 t+\frac{\sin 2t}{2}) + \omega^2 \sin2t\}}{\omega^4 - 6 \omega^2 + 25} \tag{4}\\\\
Im\{Y(t)\}&=\frac{(2\omega)( -\cos\omega t + e^{-t}\cos2t)+(5-\omega^2)\sin\omega t+\frac{e^{-t}}{2}\sin2t(\omega^3-3\omega)}{\omega^4 - 6 \omega^2 + 25}\tag{5}
\end{align}
On the hand, if \$x(t)=\sin\omega t\$, \$X(s)=\mathcal{L}\{\sin\omega t\}=\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}\$. Instead of using PFD as in Eq.2 and 3, we can separate out the conjugate pairs as:
\begin{align}
Y(s) =H(s)X(s)&=\frac{\omega}{(s^2+\omega^2)(s^2+2s+5)}=\frac{k_1s+k_2}{s^2+\omega^2}+\frac{k_3s+k_4}{s^2+2s+5} \tag{6}\\\\
Y(t)=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{Y(s)\}&=k_1\cos\omega t + \frac{k_2}{\omega} \sin\omega t + k_3 e^{-t}\cos 2t + \frac{k_4-k_3}{2}e^{-t}\sin2t\tag{7}
\end{align}
From Eq.6, we can solve \$k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4\$ in terms of \$\omega\$:
$$
k_3 = - k_1 = \frac{2\omega}{\omega^4-6\omega^2+25} ,
\space\space k_2 = \frac{5\omega-\omega^3}{\omega^4-6\omega^2+25},\space\space k_4=\frac{\omega^3-\omega}{\omega^4-6\omega^2+25} \tag{8}
$$
Substituting Eq.8 into Eq.7 yields Eq.5. By the same token, if \$x(t)=\cos\omega t\$, \$X(s)=\mathcal{L}\{\cos\omega t\}=\frac{s}{s^2+\omega^2}\$ and \$Y(t)=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{H(s)X(s)\}\$ is equal to Eq.4.
In view of this example, it showed that the response of sine input \$x(t)=\sin\omega t\$ is the imaginary part of the response of \$x(t)=e^{j\omega t}\$ and the response of cosine input \$x(t)=\cos\omega t\$ is the real part of the response of \$x(t)=e^{j\omega t}\$.  How do we prove it in general?

Isn't this normally just done with linearity? L{cos(t) + jsin(t)} = L{cos(t)} + jL{sin(t)}. Or are you asking if this applies to nonlinear systems as well?

Even with a linear time invariant system, it isn't obvious to me because Y(s) might be a complicated polynomial of $s=\sigma + j\omega$.

@LeonChang I almost think I know your question. But there is no way I'm going to try and unwind the Gordian knot output of a muddled mind to see if I can share your nightmares. So I'll just ask. Are you considering rationals, $Y_s=\frac{N_s}{D_s}=\frac{a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}{b_2s^2+b_1s+b_0}$, where  $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real, positive constants such that $a_i\ge 0$ and $b_i\gt 0$? If so, you really should read Sallen & Key,: "A Practical Method of Designing RC Active Filters", 1954, TR-50 from MIT. And then just sit and re-arrange things long enough to consider annihilator operators.

@LeonChang (I'm assuming you are already completely familiar with Euler's and how the complex versions of cos(), sin(), cosh(), sinh(), and exp() are intimately related.)

As defined,  the transfer function \$H(s)=N(s)/D(s)\$ is a rational
function in the complex variable \$s = \sigma + j\omega\$.
All of the coefficients of polynomials \$N (s)\$ and \$D(s)\$ are real, therefore the poles and zeros must
be either purely real, or appear in complex conjugate pairs. However,
the Laplace of the output function \$Y(s)\$ in Eqs. 2, 3, 4 and 5  for \$u(t)=e^{j\omega t}\$ is NOT rational because of the pole \$j\omega\$.
We can expand it into:
$$
Y(s) =H(s)\mathcal{L}\{e^{\omega t}\}=\frac{H(s)}{s-j\omega}=H(s)\frac{s+j\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}=H(s)\mathcal{L}\{cos\omega t\}+jH(s)\mathcal{L}\{sin\omega t\}
$$
Eqs. 6, 7 and 8 are for the j-term \$H(s)\mathcal{L}\{sin\omega t\}\$. This proves the
general case.
Notice that since \$H(s)\$ is rational, the coefficients like \$k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4\$ are real numbers. Even though \$Y(s)\$ is not rational, the coefficients \$A_1\$ and \$A_2\$ are complex conjugate numbers, so are \$a_1\$ and \$ a_2\$.
Thanks for the comments. I hope I've untied the knot.
